# Xcode Layout constraints: selecting divisions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I want to have two different layouts. The first layout must be applied to iPhone-3.5inch, and the second one to all the other device sizes. However, the layout I set for the compact width/compact height does not seem to take over the other layout even when I test with an iPhone-3.5inch. How can I make the first one be applied to a small device, while the other to the bigger ones?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html) compact width/compact height is size class for All iPhone models except iPhone 6Plus In landscape mode.

If you want to know whether the device is with 3.5inch screen you must do it in code.

Comment: Then is this a bug with Xcode Storyboard that it says the constraints are for 3.5inch iphones (look at the first screenshot)?